# OpenLayer Bing Maps Import Error - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, openlayers

I am trying to build a wordpress website. In one of the page I want to implement the Open Layer Bing Maps.
I am able to use Stamen but with Bing maps no hope. I downloaded the github js files from https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/tree/v6.4.3/src/ol

This is what I have tried so far using the default html and js files from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/bing-maps.html

All the files are in the mentioned directory but it's not importing without giving the full URL. After giving the link I had to change the  `import BingMaps from '/./ol/source/BingMaps';` to  `import BingMaps from '/./ol/source/BingMaps.js';` Still not working

**HTML**

```
<head>
        <title>Bing Maps</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep"></script>
        <style>
          .map {
            width: 100%;
            height:400px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
         <div id="map" class="map"></div>
         <select id="layer-select">
           <option value="Aerial">Aerial</option>
           <option value="AerialWithLabelsOnDemand" selected>Aerial with labels</option>
           <option value="RoadOnDemand">Road</option>
           <option value="CanvasDark">Road dark</option>
           <option value="OrdnanceSurvey">Ordnance Survey</option>
         </select>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
      </body>
```

Main.js

```
import '/./ol/ol.css';
import BingMaps from '/./ol/source/BingMaps';
import Map from '/./ol/Map';
import TileLayer from '/./ol/layer/Tile';
import View from '/./ol/View';

var styles = [
  'RoadOnDemand',
  'Aerial',
  'AerialWithLabelsOnDemand',
  'CanvasDark',
  'OrdnanceSurvey' ];
var layers = [];
var i, ii;
for (i = 0, ii = styles.length; i < ii; ++i) {
  layers.push(
    new TileLayer({
      visible: false,
      preload: Infinity,
      source: new BingMaps({
        key: 'BING KEY (already added a key here but not working)',
        imagerySet: styles[i],
      }),
    })
  );
}
var map = new Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [-6655.5402445057125, 6709968.258934638],
    zoom: 13,
  }),
});

var select = document.getElementById('layer-select');
function onChange() {
  var style = select.value;
  for (var i = 0, ii = layers.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    layers[i].setVisible(styles[i] === style);
  }
}
select.addEventListener('change', onChange);
onChange();
```

Can anyone help me resovle this.

Comment: not sure if this is the actual fix or not but `/./path/to/file.js` is not _usually_ a valid unix path you probably want `./path/to/file.js` presuming your calling the import from the file that has folder `path` in it.

Comment: @Joshua changing that has no effect. The error message until I use the full link. but in OpenLayers, there are multiple imports in BingMaps.js for example. so changing the import URL to a full link would mean change the whole library to full links.